# Prove there is no such nth root of unity $\zeta$ such that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\zeta) \quad$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

I'm trying to do the above problem. My approach is to use the fact that $\mathbb{Q(\zeta)}$ is the fixed subfield of the normal subgroup $A_3$ of $S_3$ and then since $A_3$ has no subgroup of the form $\{1, \tau\}$ for some transposition $\tau$, then $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ cannot happen since $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ is the fixed subfield for the subgroup $\{1, \tau\}$. I'm not sure if this correct but I think the proof is supposed to be along these lines. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I don't see why $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ should be the fixed field of $A_3$. The degree of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ can be much bigger than three.

Here's a hint: If $\zeta$ is a root of unity, then $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ is an abelian extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. That is, it is Galois with an abelian Galois group.

Now recall that every subgroup of an abelian group is a normal subgroup. What does this say about the subfields of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$?

Comment: Oh I see, so if you assume that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ is contained in  $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ then a subgroup of the abelian group which corresponds to  $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ must be a normal subgroup. But since $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}) : \mathbb{Q}$ is not a normal field extension, this can't happen?

Comment: @Crunch No, this is not what you are supposed to do. Consider the normal cloasure of $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}) : \Bbb{Q}$, call it $N$. Then it is known that $\mathrm{Gal}(N/ \Bbb{Q} )$ is isomorphic to $S_3$, which is not abelian. As a consequence, it cannot be the subgroup of an abelian group.

Comment: @Crunch Correct! That's one way to complete the argument. You can also folllow Crostul's idea, but with the correction that $Gal(N/\Bbb{Q})$ is a **quotient** of an abelian group, and hence should be abelian itself.